# How to group two different data frames into a input to a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames. The first data frame information about the material numbers that has multiple values. For example:

df1 =

```
materialNumber value
  A             10
  A             20
  A             30
  A             40
  B             1
  B             2
  B             43
  C             12 
  C             19
```

and then another dataframe that only contains a single value for the same material number seen in df1.

df2=

```
Materialnumber Value
 A               300
 B                13 
 C                18
```

I am trying to determine if the values in data frame 2 are outliers compared to what is in data frame 1. I wrote a function to do this. However, I have over 10,000 material numbers.

What is the best way to group the material numbers and run this into a function?

Comment: Would you mind to share your outlier detection function? There are diferent ways to go about your task, depending on your implementation... this is why I am asking

Comment: I use a variton of the dixon outlier detection. Calculate Q ,   Q = abs(forecast-values[which.min(abs(values- forecast))])/diff(range(values)), if Q> Q(dixon) , return material number, else null.

Comment: the tricky part seems to be the forecast - how do you predict/calculate this? (since you only have a group identifier in your data all predictions for one group should be the same... unlesse you are using some chain prediction)

Comment: @DPH this is from an external algo, I am trying to determine if the output of that algo(what is labeled "forecast") makes sense relative to the input(what is labeled "values" in the Q calc). I wouldnt worry about this too much relative to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: then you might want to rephrase your problem: it sounds like you want to apply a custom formula on one df, where the function input uses this df and also another df - correct? You showed both dfs but the formula informed uses external data. The structure of this seems to be relevant (one per group or one per case and is it a df, etc.) for the solution. In case the prediction only varies acording to groups, you could just join the prediction and compare...

Comment: would it be possible to chat through the solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236102/discussion-between-aj-jebelli-and-dph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as discussed in chat here follows the adpation of your code to df1 and df2 without further debugging:

```
dixon_test_results <- function(materialNumber,forecast){
  EKPO_Values <- df1 %>%
      dplyr::filter(materialNumber == materialNumber) %>%
      dplyr::pull(value)

  Q = abs(forecast-EKPO_Values[which.min(abs(EKPO_Values - forecast))])/diff(range(EKPO_Values))

  print(Q)
  # assumes 95% confidence
  # reference: webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/…


  dixon_q_table_val <- switch(
  length(EKPO_Values)-1, # assumes that the forecast is now part of the EKPO data set, but values assume n = 3, so  
  length(ekpo)+forecast()
  0.9411,
  0.7651,
  0.6423,
  0.5624,
  0.5077,
  0.4673,
  0.4363,
  0.4122,
  0.3922,
  0.3755,
  0.3615,
  0.3496,
  0.3389,
  0.3293,
  0.3208,
  0.3135,
  0.3068,
  0.3005,
  0.2947,
  0.2895,
  0.2851,
  0.2804,
  0.2763,
  0.2725,
  0.2686,
  0.2655,
  0.2622,
  0.2594
  )

  if (Q>dixon_q_table_val) {
      return(materialNumber)
      } else {
      return(NA_charcter_)
  }
}

df2 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(res = dixon_test_results (Materialnumber , Value))
```